# OpenCL kernels for building OpenCV incorrectly generated

Tags: opencv, opencl, osx-yosemite

I'm using CMake-GUI in OS X Yosemite 10.10.1 to build OpenCV 3.0-beta
When I generate the files in my binaries folder, I notice that the OpenCL kernels for every moduel that should be autogenerated are incomplete. 
The OpenCL kernels for each module (opencl_kernels_MODULENAME.cpp and opencl_kernels_MODULENAME.hpp) are predominantly EMPTY.
This is what one of them looks like when I open the kernels -

```
This file is auto-generated. Do not edit!
#include "precomp.hpp" 
#include "opencl_kernels_core.hpp" 
namespace cv
{
namespace ocl
{
namespace core
{

}    

}

}
```

This is quite what every kernel (cpp and hpp) looks like (for its corresponding module)
Can anyone help me out here please? Honestly, This makes NO sense to me.
NOTE: I tried building this is Ubuntu, and all of these are correctly generated.

Comment: Have you tried with OpenCV non-beta?

Answer (score 1):

I'm near uselessly late in answering this question.
But the issue was that my main folder that contained the binaries, had a *space* in the name (for example : "ocv bin" )

Interestingly enough, when I removed that *space* I got it to build smoothly.

Sadly, I never really looked into why this happened, hence I cannot give a real reason why. 
If anyone reading this can point me to the right direction to figure out the reason why, I would highly appreciate it.

Again, apologies for the late response. Time flies when you move from one problem to the next!